# Performance comparison of OpenCV-Python interfaces, cv and cv2

Tags: python, performance, opencv, computer-vision

A few days back, I started using new OpenCV-Python interface, `cv2`.

My question is regarding the comparison of `cv` and `cv2` interface.

Regarding the ease of use, new `cv2` interface has improved far greater, and it is really easy and fun to work with `cv2`.

But what about speed?

I made two small code snipplets, one in `cv` and another in `cv2`, to check the performances. Both does the same function, access pixels of an image, test it, make some modifications, etc.

Below is the code:

---

*`cv2 interface`*:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import cv2

gray = cv2.imread('sir.jpg',0)
width = gray.shape[0]
height = gray.shape[1]
h = np.empty([width,height,3])
t = time.time()
for i in xrange(width):
    for j in xrange(height):
        if gray[i,j]==127:
            h[i,j]=[255,255,255]
        elif gray[i,j]>127:
            h[i,j]=[0,0,255-gray[i,j]]
        else:
            h[i,j]=[gray[i,j],0,0]
t2 = time.time()-t
print "time taken = ",t2
```

=====================================================

And result is:

time taken =  14.4029130936

======================================================

***cv interface:***

```
import cv,time

gray = cv.LoadImage('sir.jpg',0)
h = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(gray),8,3)

t=time.time()

for i in xrange(gray.width):
    for j in xrange(gray.height):
        k = cv.Get2D(gray,j,i)[0]
        if k==127:
            cv.Set2D(h,j,i,(255,255,255))
        elif k>127:
            cv.Set2D(h,j,i,(0,0,255-k))
        else:
            cv.Set2D(h,j,i,(k,0,0))

t2 = time.time()-t
print "time taken = ",t2
cv.ShowImage('img',h)
cv.WaitKey(0)
```

======================================================

The result is:

time taken =  1.16368889809

=======================================================

See, here old `cv` is about `12 times faster` than `cv2`. And resulting images are same. (input image is of size 720x540)

Why does this happen?

Is cv2 slower compared to cv?

Or am I making any mistake here? Is there a faster method in cv2 for the above code?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The image returned by cv2.imread() is an array object of NumPy. So you can use NumPy's functions to speedup calculation.

The following program shows how to speedup your origin for loop version by using item(), itemset() method of ndarray object.

```
import time
import numpy as np
import cv2

gray = cv2.imread('lena_full.jpg',0)
height, width = gray.shape
h = np.empty((height,width,3), np.uint8)

t = time.time()
for i in xrange(height):
    for j in xrange(width):
        k = gray.item(i, j)
        if k == 127:
            h.itemset(i, j, 0, 255)
            h.itemset(i, j, 1, 255)
            h.itemset(i, j, 2, 255)
        elif k > 127:
            h.itemset(i, j, 0, 0)
            h.itemset(i, j, 1, 0)
            h.itemset(i, j, 2, 255-k)
        else:
            h.itemset(i, j, 0, k)
            h.itemset(i, j, 1, 0)
            h.itemset(i, j, 2, 0)
print time.time()-t
```

And the following program show how to create the palette first, and use NumPy's array index to get the result:

```
t = time.time()
palette = []
for i in xrange(256):
    if i == 127:
        palette.append((255, 255, 255))
    elif i > 127:
        palette.append((0,0,255-i))
    else:
        palette.append((i, 0, 0))
palette = np.array(palette, np.uint8)

h2 = palette[gray]

print time.time() - t

print np.all(h==h2)
```

The output is:

```
0.453000068665
0.0309998989105
True
```

The cv version output is :

```
0.468999862671
```

*Note: the length of axis 0 is the height of the image, the length of axis 1 is the width of the image*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you add a few more details? Do you know a better way for the above procedure, any faster numpy functions etc?

Comment: @arkiaz, I modified your cv2 for loop version, and now it's the same speed as cv version. And I added a numpy version to speedup more.

Comment: Thanks, your first method gives comparable speed with cv, although code become little big. Result obtained with my image `t=1.127`. But your second method gives a very good result of `t=0.054`, but gives a large black screen( ie wrong output). Why is it?

Comment: @arkiaz, Please change the line "palette = np.array(palette)" to "palette = np.array(palette, np.uint8)", this will solve the problem.

Comment: well, `palette=np.array(palette,np.uint8)` solved the problem, and it is pretty fast, `t=0.503`. Thanks.

Comment: wow. that is fast. Thanks for this example HYRY. very very helpful in using numpy and cv2.

Comment: But I never see `h` get set back to `gray`. That conversion would need to be taken into account. How do you even convert back from `h` to an opencv data structure?