# Image Processing - MATLAB or OpenCV with Python, which is faster?

Tags: python, image, matlab, opencv

I have this Image Processing project in MATLAB which might be a few thousand lines of code. It uses the Image Processing toolbox extensively. I need to port this code to C or C++ for speed improvements. The code has already been profiled in MATLAB. The plan is to use OpenCV and some other C/C++ libraries. However, I'm not very proficient at C or C++.

My question is if I code in python instead using the OpenCV library will I achieve any speed improvements? If yes, how much?

Also, how do these 3 approaches compare speed wise, when talking about Image Processing computations:

1. Using the OpenCV library as it is
2. Using OpenCV with Python bindings
3. Using MATLAB

Thanks.

Comment: matlab is def the slowest by far

Comment: @Smash: this depends a lot on what kind of processing is being done (and on the quality of the code).

Comment: Found a close answer on Stack Overflow itself. Should have checked the site more thoroughly beforehand. My bad. Here's the answer link <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432800/does-performance-differs-between-python-or-c-coding-of-opencv>

Comment: If you use OpenCV C/C++ - way faster than MATLAB. Python bindings still much faster than MATLAB just don't implement loops and iterations, instead use smart numpy array manipulation tricks.

Comment: This is not a "Processing" question - the Processing tag is for the "Processing" programming language, it's probably a good idea to remove the tag from your post.

Comment: @Will Is this not a different question? `Matlab vs Python` rather than `Python vs C++` as in the original question?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: Look up three comments.  And, no, that didn't just appear out of nowhere like it just did.