# Fastest way to compute & feed an arbitrary color centroid in an image to PHP

Tags: php, python, opencv, imagemagick, color-detection

I'm looking for the fastest way to compute a directional vector based on an arbitrary color in an image (a Rpi camera, but a JPEG file for testing is OK for now), a.k.a. tracking a colored ball project.  Please note that *the resulting vector (or centroid coordinates, whatever) needs to be passed to PHP for the program execution*, so the solution I'm looking for needs to end with PHP, but can be anything before, given it can be implemented on both Windows and Linux.

Consider an input JPEG image:

[image]

Here are 2 example directional vectors I'm after, obtained based on a 1) teal color input and 2) purple color input.  Obviously, only 1 vector will ever be asked at a time, I put 2 to demonstrate multiple examples into 1 image, but it's always gonna be only 1 vector at a time.  Note that the resulting vectors ("v") are standardized to -1.0 (bottom/left) to +1.0 (bottom/right) so that zero is the middle of the picture.

[image]

Here are the various solutions I've implemented/tested so far and how much time the whole process takes, based on a 960x640 JPEG picture, but the implemented solution will be tied to a Rpi camera input, I do not have the camera yet so I use a JPEG image until the camera arrives from China.

1) **2700ms** : Use GD2 that is bundled with PHP, for loop over each pixels, push pixels matching ~10% RGB values in XY arrays, average the XY arrays, compute/normalize directional vector from XY arrays.

```
$arr_matching_pixels = array('arr_x' => array(), 'arr_y' => array());
for($y = 0; $y < $h - 1; $y++){
    for($x = 0; $x < $w - 1; $x++){
        $arr_pixel = imagecolorsforindex($img, imagecolorat($img, $x, $y));
        if(abs($arr_pixel['red'] - $arr_seek_color['red']) < 30){
            if(abs($arr_pixel['green'] - $arr_seek_color['green']) < 30){
                if(abs($arr_pixel['blue'] - $arr_seek_color['blue']) < 30){
                    array_push($arr_matching_pixels['arr_x'], $x);
                    array_push($arr_matching_pixels['arr_y'], $y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
// Compute centroid of color... etc...
```

2) **700ms** : Same as #1 except begin by resizing the canvas by 50% (acceptable loss) using `imagecreatefromjpeg('_test_cam_img.jpg');`

3) **560ms** : Same as #2 except use ImageMagick with a pixel iterator loop to read the pixels

```
$imagick = new Imagick(realpath($o_img));
$arr_matching_pixels = array('arr_x' => array(), 'arr_y' => array());
$arr_pixel = array();
$iterator = $imagick->getPixelIterator();
foreach($iterator as $y => $pixels){
    foreach($pixels as $x => $pixel){
        $arr_pixel = $pixel->getColor();
        if(abs($arr_pixel['r'] - $arr_seek_color['red']) < 30){
            if(abs($arr_pixel['g'] - $arr_seek_color['green']) < 30){
                if(abs($arr_pixel['b'] - $arr_seek_color['blue']) < 30){
                    array_push($arr_matching_pixels['arr_x'], $x);
                    array_push($arr_matching_pixels['arr_y'], $y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
// Compute centroid of color... etc...
```

4) **340ms** : Call the system's ImageMagick binary via the exec() function, pass it the image location, the chroma/color key, a resize by 50% param, a 10% fuzz param, and the sparse-color: modifier to extract a textual (CSV-like) list representation of desired pixels, then use PHP to loop over each line, explode commas and push all pixels in XY arrays, average the XY arrays, compute/normalize directional vector from XY arrays.  I noted that calling exec() proves to be quite slower than executing the same command directly from the Windows command line.

```
$imagick = new Imagick(realpath($o_img));
$out = exec('"E:\Users\Ben\Roaming Apps\imagemagick-6.9.3\convert" E:\wamp64\www\test_cam_img.jpg -resize 50% -fuzz 10% +transparent rgb(' . $arr_seek_color['red'] . ',' . $arr_seek_color['green'] . ',' . $arr_seek_color['blue'] . ') sparse-color:');
$arr_lines = explode(' ', $out);
$arr_matching_pixels = array('arr_x' => array(), 'arr_y' => array());
foreach($arr_lines as $str_line){
    $arr_xy_coords = explode(',', $str_line);
    array_push($arr_matching_pixels['arr_x'], $arr_xy_coords[0]);
    array_push($arr_matching_pixels['arr_y'], $arr_xy_coords[1]);
}
// Compute centroid of color... etc...
```

5) **32ms** : PHP creates an "in" text file containing the image path and the chroma/color key and begins looping until it reads an "out" text file.  A python+OpenCV script already/always runs a (stoppable) infinite loop constantly looking for an "in" text file and when it exists, it read it, explodes the values, makes a 1-bit mask using the HSV values ~10% (cv2.inRange) from the "in" file, then makes an array using cv2.findNonZero(mask) and computes the array mean value and writes it to an "out" text file that PHP immediately reads, containing the directional vector value.  This is by far, the fastest way I have found, but it is awkward, because it implies that the python script will have to be programmed in a CRONJOB and monitored/relaunched in a single instance if it crashes.

```
file_put_contents('_avg_color_coords_in.txt', $o_img . "\n" . $arr_seek_color['h'] . ',' . $arr_seek_color['s'] . ',' . $arr_seek_color['l']);

$starttime = time();
while((time() - $starttime) < 5){ // Max 5 seconds (exaggerated)
    if(file_exists('_avg_color_coords_out.txt')){
        $dir_vector = (float) file_get_contents('_avg_color_coords_out.txt');
        if(!@unlink('_avg_color_coords_out.txt')){
            sleep(1);
            unlink('_avg_color_coords_out.txt');
        }
        break;
    }
    usleep(2000);
}
// $dir_vector ("v", the centroid of the color) is already computed by Python


// ---------- PYTHON SCRIPT ----------
import math
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import time

#cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#while (1):
#    _, frame = cap.read()
if(os.path.exists('_avg_color_coords_stop.txt')):
    exit()
while not os.path.exists('_avg_color_coords_in.txt'):
    time.sleep(0.002)
f = open('_avg_color_coords_in.txt', 'r')
imgsrc = f.readline().rstrip('\n')
rgbcol = [int(x) for x in f.readline().rstrip('\n').split(',')]
frame = cv2.imread(imgsrc)
h, w = frame.shape[:2]

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hfacl = rgbcol[0] / 360 * 180 * 0.95
hfach = rgbcol[0] / 360 * 180 * 1.05
sfacl = rgbcol[1] / 100 * 255 * 0.9
sfach = rgbcol[1] / 100 * 255 * 1.1
vfacl = rgbcol[2] / 100 * 255 * 0.9
vfach = rgbcol[2] / 100 * 255 * 1.1
lower_color = np.array([hfacl, sfacl, vfacl]) # 0..180, 0..255, 0..255 not percentage!
upper_color = np.array([hfach, sfach, vfach]) # 0..180, 0..255, 0..255 not percentage!
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_color, upper_color)
#cv2.imshow('mask', mask)

points = cv2.findNonZero(mask)
if(points.any()):
    avg = np.mean(points, axis=0)
else:
    avg = [0,0]
#print(avg)

v = -math.atan(((w * 0.5) - avg[0][0]) / (h - avg[0][1])) / (3.1415 * 0.5);
f2 = open('_avg_color_coords_out.txt', 'w+')
f2.write("%s" % str(v))

#    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xff
#    if k == 27:
#        break

#cv2.destroyAllWindows()
#cap.release()

f2.close()
f.close()
os.remove('_avg_color_coords_in.txt')
```

6) **38ms** : Same as #5 except begin by resizing the canvas by 50% (acceptable loss) which doesn't seem to speed up things at all, and even seems counterproductive a little bit.

Is there a faster way or is this optimal? This will run every second on a 900mhz Rpi, so it needs to be quick.  I think 30ms on a 900mhz CPU will be around 150-200ms (not tested yet, waiting for the camera to ship)

Comment: 30ms are 30ms on all CPUs. Except they are nearing c.

Comment: No, it's 30ms on a 4ghz AMD desktop CPU.  I foresee it being at least 5 to 6 times slower on the Rpi 900mhz CPU.  Could even be slower FAIK.

Comment: That a rather naive calculation taking into account that the Raspberry Pi has a completely different architecture.

Comment: pessimistic* ;-) I hope to be wrong and it's faster than I expected...

Comment: Do you think that the latest Python+OpenCV for ARM will take advantage of the Rpi quad cores or no?

Comment: I would suggest rewriting your Python&OpenCV solution in C++&OpenCV. An even faster way would be to write a [C module for PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.structure.php) that integrates directly with Rpi's  Broadcom chip, and take advantage of [MMAL](http://www.jvcref.com/files/PI/documentation/html/index.html) decoder/pipeline features.

Comment: @emcconville Thanks for posting! Tough, your claim seems wrong, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432800/does-performance-differ-between-python-or-c-coding-of-opencv Now,compiling a C module for PHP is indeed a very interesting idea, but I'm looking for something a little simpler at the moment.  I'm not exactly an engineer, just a simple hobbyist making a prototype mostly for myself at the moment, hence why I use PHP instead of a direct C approach, which would probably be a million times faster.  PHP lets me develop/test on Windows and then deploy DIRECTLY to my Rpi.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for replying to my question! Indeed that Q might not be fully detailed but I'll try to append/explain everything you need to help me solve this.  Please note that I am sure that you are a very competent person.  There is no need to feel "stupid" or anything like that.  Basically my question is: What is the highest performance way to script a routine that returns the average of all pixels of a given color in a given image? See in my ex, I input purple as RGB and the pink vector arrow represents the average coordinates of a purple blob. Let me know if this is still unclear.

Comment: @MarkSetchell "v" is the computed linear vector as an example.  See the purple blob at the end of the pink arrow? All the purple pixels throughout the whole picture were averaged, which gives the mean of the purple area, then "v" represents this vector.  The Q is not how to compute v, but how to obtain v the fastest way.  In Q you can see 6 approaches I took starting with GD2 (2.7 seconds) then Imagick for PHP, then Imagick binary via PHP exex() then OpenCV via Python.  In any case, the process starts with PHP and ends with PHP.  Whatever is in between needs to be as fast as possible.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Oh and the values you see printed for "v" is just because I standardize "v" between -1.0 (absolute bottom/left) to +1.0 (absolute bottom/right) so zero is the middle (top, middle or bottom, doesn't matter) of the picture.

Comment: Yes yes, PHP is slow, I know.  But for serving web based apps and triggering all sorts of system calls, GPIO exports and such, it's great.  Also, about the JPEG vs PNG, you're right :P I have found that out yesterday after posting a PNG.  I had mistakenly uploaded a PNG image, but I assure you that the input is JPEG, not PNG.  It is indeed much faster to process JPEG than PNG I have found out.

Comment: @MarkSetchell As you can see in the Q processing the image with PHP (method #1) is the LEAST efficient method of the 6, so why would I end up using method #1? Python reads the cam just fine?

Answer (score 1):

I had a quick go in [php-vips](https://github.com/libvips/php-vips):

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Jcupitt\Vips;

$image = Vips\Image::newFromFile($argv[1], ['access' => 'sequential']);

# Target colour in RGB.
$target = [50, 10, 100];

# Select pixels where all bands are less than 10 away from the target.
# (and render it to memory ... we'll be reusing this mask image).
# The mask image will have one band with 0 for false and 255 for true.
$mask = $image->subtract($target)->abs()->less(10)->bandand()->copyMemory();

# The number of set pixels in the mask.
$n_set = $mask->avg() * $mask->width * $mask->height / 255;

# Handy for debugging: uncomment to write the mask image for inspection.
# $mask->writeToFile("x.png");

# Make a two-band image where band 0 is x coordinates and band 1 is y
# coordinates.
$coords = Vips\Image::xyz($mask->width, $mask->height);

# Make an indexed histogram: sum $coords at each position.
$pos = $coords->hist_find_indexed($mask);

# fetch the sum of the 255 value (true) pixels
[$x_sum, $y_sum] = $pos->getpoint(255, 0);

echo("x = " . $x_sum / $n_set . "\n");
echo("y = " . $y_sum / $n_set . "\n");
```

I can run it like this:

```
$ time ./locate-rgb.php ~/pics/x.jpg
x = 483.375
y = 487.75
real    0m0.079s
user    0m0.085s
sys 0m0.022s
```

So about 80ms on this modest laptop. That includes PHP startup and shutdown, and decompressing the JPG image.

That's only going to work in very constrained lighting and camera setups, but perhaps that's OK? It would be easy to make the ball detection fancier, but of course it would slow it down a bit.

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting! On Linux, I would have been done with installing this yesterday, but how the heck do you get this going on Windows tough? I grabbed the vips-dev-w64-web-8.8.3.zip archive and found vips.exe inside along with a bunch of lib*.dll files but no php_vips.dll file.  Would you be so kind as to append to your answer exact sequence to get this solution going from a vanilla WAMP (Apache 2.4, PHP 7.1) on Windows 7 64-bits? That would be much appreciated.  Final solution will be deployed on Raspbian, but for testing, I need the same solution on a Windows machine :(

Comment: Sorry, php-vips doesn't work on Windows. I don't think it'd be too hard to get it going, but no one's done it, as far as I know.

Comment: Personally, I would install Ubuntu (pretty close to raspbian) in a VM on your Windows machine and develop there. It'll be closer to your deployment platform, and native php extensions will be much simpler to install.

Comment: Oh.  Well you know what? Let's keep this Q up for a couple weeks, then I'll receive my Rpi cam module and I'll delevelop directly on the Rpi in a Linux environment... F Windows.  I'll be sure to try your method.  Also, Mark Setchell raised a good point in conjunction with your solution: If I were to use PHP from A to Z then how would I efficiently read the camera from PHP on a Rpi? Is that even a thing? (never bothered to check because I would assume the two are popular so they must have some kind of compatibility together but now I'm in doubt!)

Comment: Linux cameras connect with v4l2. From php you'd need to open `/dev/mycameradevice` and do a series of read() and ioctl() calls. It's not difficult, but of course it is one more thing you'd have to write. I don't know if anyone has written a php modules that does this for you -- php is mostly used on servers, and they don't tend to have cameras.

Comment: I'd have no problem with doing this if the performance is adequate, obviously it's not gonna be on par with a full Python solution, I'm very well aware of this.  Reading /dev/ is actually what I've been doing for 2 years to read/write GPIO pins and while the performance is not good, it's good enough for ~1Mhz operations, which fits 100% of my needs.  Sensors don't need 1 million reads a second.